# How to detect that PIE/ASLR has been enabled for my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, security

I am enabling PIE (position-independent executable)/ASLR (address space layout randomization) for an iPhone app by using the `"-w -pie"` linking option flag. Is there any way I can ensure that things are now set to work as advertised? I tried printing the address of a variable *(Edit: and a function)* with NSLog and it comes up the same each time. Am I doing it right?

Comment: I have PIE flag. My question what can make my not decompiled by Clutch and Clutch2. any one ?

Answer (score 7):

I know this thread is old, but there is no good answer yet in case someone else stumbles upon it.  To check if the PIE flag is set is very simple, just run this command:

```
otool -hv /path/to/App.app/app
```

Where [APP] is the executable created after building (not the ipa but the executable, binary file).

You should see something like this:

```
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00     EXECUTE    19       2708   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL PIE
```

otool should be included in Xcode but if you don't have it you can install it in Xcode preferences > Downloads > Command Line Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Examine function addresses, not variable addresses.

Comment: I did that as well, and still no luck.

Comment: you are probably printing relative addresses and not absolute address. that is  why you are getting the same every time.